# combining jquery magnificPopup and setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using magnificPopup jquery plugin to create a pop-up window when a button is pressed:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center center-block open-popup-link" href="#module_1"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Start</a>

$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true 
});


<div id="module_1" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
     <h3>Hi </h3>
</div>
```

This works fine as excepted but I'm trying to insert it dynamically with PHP, jquery sends a request to the PHP class/method the method checks the database to see if a boolen is set and if so echo's out the above button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#running").load('<?php echo URL. "hdp/testRunning/1"; ?>');
    }, 1000);
});

echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center center-block open-popup-link" href="#module_1"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Start Test</a>';
```

This echo's onto the page as expected but when the button is clicked it doesn't give the pop-up window like it does when the button is simply static in the HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: I should mention as well, I've used the button static and well as dynamically inserting it so they both on the page at the same time, the static one works fine but the one included with PHP doesn't work.